# addEventListener() not working

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

Ok, so I tried to make this page with an addEventListener function, to address the clicking of a button; It didn't work. I narrowed it down by deleting everything but the basic elements needed for the listener, and am left with the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function init(){
    document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("mousedown", function(){
        alert("Test successful");
    });
}
body.onload = init();
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="test">Click</button>
</body>
</html>
```

which didn't work either, so I know the issue is in my syntax of the above. Mind you, when I took away `body.onload = init();` and instead put `onload="init()"` into the body tag, it did work :O Problem is, I don't want to have it inline. Any suggestions?

Note: Do bear in mind that this question is **not** about how there is a bug in JS, even if the title may suggest so, it is about how I can't get it to work since I've probably got the syntax wrong. Please feel free to rename it if you wish.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

First of all, you should access the body element through `document.body`. However, `onload` is defined on `window`, so you actually need:

```
window.onload = init();
```

However, that would execute the `init()` method and store the return value in `window.onload`. Obviously, that's not what you want: you want the `init` function to act as `onload` handler. Therefore, you should have written:

```
window.onload = init;
```

Although I'd recommend using `addEventListener` for that as well:

```
window.addEventListener("load", init);
```

Comment: The third solution is by far the best :) Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

body.onload = init();

Not the way to refer to body, use window instead-
and don't call the method there, reference it (without parentheses)

**window.onload=init;**

Pass the third argument, even if it is false-

```
function init(){
     document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("mousedown", function(){
         alert("Test successful");
     },false);
}
```

And note that IE before version #9 does not support addEventListener.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because `body` is not defined, the correct is document.body.
Also, maybe the document.body is not defined yet because the `head` tag is rendered before the `body` tag, so the better is to check when the `window` or the `document` is loaded.
Try this code:

```
function init(){
    document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("mousedown", function(){
        alert("Test successful");
    });
}
document.addEventListener('load',init);//Or also, window.addEventListener
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script>
        window.addEventListener('load', () => {
            document.getElementById('test').addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
                alert("Test successful");
            });
        })
</script>
```